# When handling "select all" of aggrid - returned number of selected rows is 0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid

I am trying to handle "select all" event ( or select all in page ) of AgGrid and to get selected rows. Here is body of handler . The grid with mode "Server Side".
According to documentation of agGrid - for server side it is not recommended to use
getSelectedRows() / getSelectedNodes(). Thus it was used getServerSideSelectionState
Here is body of selection changed event

```
const onSelectionChangedHandler = (event: SelectionChangedEvent) => {
    ///Some code 
    console.log('selection changed event: ', event.api.getServerSideSelectionState()?.toggledNodes?.length);
    ...
};
```

Column definition contains :

```
headerCheckboxSelection: true,
headerCheckboxSelectionCurrentPageOnly: true,
```

The question is - what is correct / recommended way to get selected rows ?
Thanks in advance